# How do I pass in variables to a Class in python, and then have those variables be used in other called classes/objects?

Tags: python, oop

I have a class called createEmbeds and I want to pass the variables pretrained_path, ffn_weight_file, bert_ffn_weight_file, and embedding_file to it.

I then want those variables to be passed when creating new objects within this class. I have imported other classes, and now I want to make instances of them by passing in variables.

I then want to pass those objects to another object.

Here is my attempt

```
from Scripts.predictor_functions import QAEmbed, FaissTopK, RetreiveQADoc

class createEmbeds:
    def __init__(self, pretrained_path = None, ffn_weight_file = None, \
        bert_ffn_weight_file = 'models/bertffn_crossentropy/bertffn',  embedding_file = 'qa_embeddings/bertffn_crossentropy.csv'):
            self.pretrained_path = pretrained_path
            self.ffn_weight_file = ffn_weight_file
            self.bert_ffn_weight_file = bert_ffn_weight_file
            self.embedding_file = embedding_file

    def get_qa_embed(self):
        qa_embed = QAEmbed(
            pretrained_path=self.pretrained_path,
            ffn_weight_file=self.ffn_weight_file,
            bert_ffn_weight_file=self.bert_ffn_weight_file
        )
        return qa_embed

    def get_faiss_topk(self):
        faiss_topk = FaissTopK(self.embedding_file)
        return faiss_topk

    doc = RetreiveQADoc(get_qa_embed(self), get_faiss_topk(self))
```

I am getting a

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Error

Full error

```
1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Scripts/inference_question_to_topk_functions2.py in createEmbeds()
     26         return faiss_topk
     27 
---> 28     doc = RetreiveQADoc(get_qa_embed(self), get_faiss_topk(self))
     29 
     30 #     print(doc.predict('i have a headache.',

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: You have your methods set up to have a different `pretrained_path` etc. for each instance. What is that last line defining `doc` as a class variable supposed to do? Which instance do you think `self` is referring to? Perhaps that line should be `self.doc = ...` and be placed in the `__init__` if you want a separate one for each instance.

Comment: `What is that last line defining doc as a class variable supposed to do? ` it's supposed to return an embedding based on the output of the other objects fed into it. `Which instance do you think self is referring to?` I thought `self` refers to the `createEmbeds` instance. So that the functions will take that `self` and know that the variables given are the ones defined in the class __init__. `self.doc = ... and be placed in the __init__ if you want a separate one for each instance. ` would that make placing everything else in __init__?

Comment: Do you want the `doc` to be a class variable which is shared among all instances? If so, it needs to avoid attempts to retrieve instance data (like `self`, which is not a keyword and hasn't been defined in that scope at that point). If you want `doc` to be an instance variable, with each instance having its own unique one, you need to decide when it should be created, save it as `self.doc` rather than `doc`, in a method.